# Unity light object not affect some parts of a 3D model

Tags: unity

So far I've used Unity only for 2D projects. But now I need to implement a 3D scene in my game. I downloaded a tree model from the asset store and placed it in my scene. I couldn't help but notice that my light objects do not affect some parts of such tree.

It affects the leaves, but the trunk remains dark. Even with a point light right next to the trunk, it doesn't seem to be affected by the light.

The tree I refer to is the Shanty Town one: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/44

Since I don't know much about 3D, I've been meaning to ask if this is normal behavior (the fact that the tree's trunk is not affected by light objects) and if I am expected to see other models with the same issue. Is there a way to fix this? I have someone that will make some 3D models for my game, but now I am concerned that my light objects will not properly work on his models.

Comment: Check Use Light Probes on the mesh renderer

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a light problem in Unity, not a tree problem.

In Unity, the amount of point lights are limited.
If you have more than 4, the colors do not blend properly.
If you have way more than 4, the Unity choses to light up only the closest light.

This is very annoying, but it's a way to prevent Unity from crashing.

If you aren't using point lights, you should not be experiencing this problem.